# Apache view executed post request

Tags: apache

In `apache` exists `action.log`, where is logged all viewed url. How I can found all `POST` request to page `example.com/api` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Apache's mod_dumpio.

**mod_dumpio** allows for the logging of all input received by Apache and/or all output sent by Apache to be logged (dumped) to the error.log file.

The data logging is done right after SSL decoding (for input) and right before SSL encoding (for output). As can be expected, this can produce extreme volumes of data, and should only be used when debugging problems.